# Why is the timestamp of the RTP packet not increased?

Tags: timestamp, rtsp, rtp

When analyzing the RTP packet, I find that the timestamp may decrease from the previous frame, while the sequence number increases monotonically.

```
E.g.#1 : seqnum: 17233, ts: 225300783 -> seqnum: 17234, ts: 225297783 -> seqnum: 17235, ts: 225303783 -> seqnum: 17236, ts: 225318783 -> seqnum: 17249, ts: 225312783
```

Because the timestamp order of the RTP packet is out of whack. I had a big problem when I used this timestamp to sync audio and video. Why is the timestamp of the RTP packet messy, but the serial number normal? What can I do to get a normal timestamp?